# How do I change the language of C# error hints?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Since omnisharp 1.16 update (don't know if it is the point) I have error hints in my system's language (Russian).
But my VSCode locale is English.
Where I can set error hints' language back to english?
I don't have any localization language packs for .Net in the system.

[image: Errors I am talking about picture]

Comment: You can go to the developers at GitHub https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the workaround to set error hint back to English. As described here:
https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2513

Open your "OmniSharp" log and find the path to OmniSharp from the beginning of the log, eg:

OmniSharp server started.

Path: C:\Users\rchande.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.16.1.omnisharp\1.32.5\OmniSharp.exe

Navigate to the directory eg

C:\Users\rchande.vscode-insiders\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.16.1.omnisharp\1.32.5,

and enter the subfolder that corresponds to your system language. In my case, the folder would be "ru" because the system language is Russian. Remove all the DLLs whose name starts with Microsoft.CodeAnalysis. Or rename the folder.